# How do I clean up hierarchical tags when adding new levels in Digikam?

Tags: tagging, digikam

I often find myself restructuring and refining my hierarchical tags in `digikam`.
For instance, assume that an image is assigned `Tag 2` which resides below `Tag 1`:

```
Tag 1
  Tag 2 (assigned to image)
```

When I now decide that I would like to have `Tag 3` below `Tag 2` and add `Tag 3` to the image, then the image is assigned both, `Tag 2` and `Tag 3`.

```
Tag 1
  Tag 2     (assigned to image)
      Tag 3 (assigned to image)
```

Is it possible to clean up the upper-level tags and remove all tags above the lowest-level tag in the hierarchy from the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are not able to do this, because it would defeat the point of the nesting.

You can create the same tag a second time outside that hierarchy, but the point of

```
Animal
    Mammal
        Cat
        Human
    Insect
        Bumblebee
        Ant
```

is that `Ant` and `Cat` are both `Animal`s, but not every `Animal` is a `Mammal` and/or `Cat`.

Therefore, when you look for the tag `Animal`, you will find all of the `Animal`s. When you look for `Mammal`s, you will only find `Mammal`s - and so on.

If, on the other hand, you had a flat hiearchy:

```
Animal
Mammal
Cat
Human
Insect
Bumblebee
Ant
```

then there is no way that an image only tagged `Cat` will be found when looking for `Animal`.

In theory, you could have a routine that does the hierarchy-thing automatically, so while the picture only holds the tag `Cat`, your program puts it in `Animals` and so on. I am not sure if DigiKam (or any other program) can do that, and it would probably not be the best idea, as there is a chance that tags are ambiguous (e.g. `Cat` could also refer to [Caterpillar Inc.'s machinery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Caterpillar_Inc._machines)).